# Rails: sign out logged in user on event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise

I'm using Rail3 with [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) gem. It does a great job when you need to lock user from signing in.

But it works just for new login attempts.
If he is already logged in - it won't sign him out immediately.

Here's is the typical use case:

Given admin user
when detects suspicious activity of certain user he locks it with `malicious_user.lock('locking-reason')`

```
% can config/initializers/session_store.rb
AppFoo::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_foo_session'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given HTTP's statelessness, you can't immediately log out a user because you will need to wait until they make another request to your server. You could get around this via a push service I suppose, but that would be overkill.

My solution would be to add that person to a blacklist and then check if they're on the blacklist whenever they try to access a section intended for logged-on users only. This will render them unable to log on until you decide whether or not their activity is suspicious.

**Example:**

***User is suspected of intolerable activity***

Admin wants to check this out, so they temporarily add the user to the blacklist.

***User clicks on an area of the page they were currently on when added to the blacklist.***

Code checks for loggin status and blacklisted users.

***Since the user is blacklisted, they are informed that they need to sign in to access the content***

Once the user tries to sign in again you can inform them that their account has been temporarily disabled (or you can do this in the previous step).

Answer (score 1):

perhaps the easiest way would be to redirect the user to the logout action when you lock them so:

```
malicious_user.lock('locking-reason')
redirect_to '/logout' and return
```

I'm not familiar with Devise so this may not be the best solution or even possible but it's how I would approach the problem

Comment: redirect_to '/logout' will redirect Admin user not the malicious. I'm locking users from Admin

Answer (score 1):

Use a before_filter in the ApplicationController that will do the following

```
 before_filter :kick_out_blocked_user


 protected

 def kick_out_blocked_user       
   unless current_user.try(:active?)
      redirect_to destroy_user_session_path        
   end
 end
```